# How to use BERT pre-trained model in Keras Embedding layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, nlp

How do I use a pre-trained BERT model like `bert-base-uncased` as weights in the Embedding layer in Keras?

Currently, I am generating word embddings using BERT model and it takes a lot of time. And I am assigning those weights like in the cide shown below

```
model.add(Embedding(307200, 1536, input_length=1536, weights=[embeddings]))
```

I searched on internet but the method is given in PyTorch. I need to do it in Keras. Please help.

Comment: Embedding has a `embeddings_initializer` arguments, you could use it like this `embeddings_initializer=np.ones((307200, 1536))`.

Comment: That is not what I asked actually. If I initiliaze the `embeddings_initiliazer` as you said, wherein I will pass the BERT pre-trained model? In my code, the `weights` are embedding layer that I have manually generated. Instead of this, I want a pre-trained model for weights.

Comment: As far as I understand, you just want to pass the BERT pre-trained mode to a new model and use the pre-trained embeddings to fine-tune the new model, right?

Comment: Yes, I want BERT pre-trained embeddings to be used in my model.

Comment: Then [hub.KerasLayer](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tf2_saved_model#using_a_savedmodel_in_keras) is what you should use. You can first save the BERT model with `SavedModel` format, then load it with hub.KerasLayer as a keras layer which can be added to other models.

Comment: Okay, great! Thank you very much.

Comment: I am using hub.KerasLayer with this code `hub_url = "https://cdn.huggingface.co/xlnet-base-cased-pytorch_model.bin"` but it is giving an error `OSError: https://cdn.huggingface.co/xlnet-base-cased-pytorch_model.bin does not appear to be a valid module.`

Comment: It seems that you use the `pytorch` model with hub.KerasLayer? It may not fit, AFAIK, KerasLayer only support SavedModel format tesorflow model. You could either search pretrained bert model on [tensorflow hub](https://tfhub.dev/) or train and save the model by yourself.